# Caffeine Removal Listener functionality does not work on its own

Tags: java, caching, caffeine-cache

I was trying to use the removalListener functionality of Caffeine Cache, but it does not work as excepted. Below is the code tried:

```
public class CaffeineCacheConfig {

    @Autowired EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        CaffeineCacheManager cacheManager = new CaffeineCacheManager("customer");
        cacheManager.setCaffeine(caffeineCacheBuilder());
        return cacheManager;
    }

    Caffeine<Object, Object> caffeineCacheBuilder() {
        System.out.println("loading data");
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .initialCapacity(100)
                .maximumSize(500)
                .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .removalListener((key, value, cause) -> {
                    System.out.println("key: "+ key);
                    System.out.println("value: "+value);
                    System.out.println("cause: "+cause);
                    if (cause.wasEvicted()) employeeRepository.save(new Employee("Test Employee"));
                });

    }

}
```

As per expectation, the key, value and cause should be printed in console and also data should be inserted in DB after 2 minutes has passed for every entry in the cache.

Please help me understand if my understanding is correct or this is some issue.

Comment: You can add a scheduler if you want prompt expiration, or else it piggybacks on other activity. You can read about it here: https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Cleanup

Comment: @BenManes, it worked after following your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @BenManes Even in the provided link it says `The scheduling is best-effort and does not make any hard guarantees of when an expired entry will be removed`. Strangely, there is no easy guaranteed way to remove after the expiry.

Comment: @mukund It is a necessary caveat to state, but is not a practical concern. Java's `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` makes a similar remark _"Delayed tasks execute no sooner than they are enabled, but without any real-time guarantees about when, after they are enabled, they will commence."_